# Excel VBA: "Worksheet_Change" function uses ".EntireRow.Insert" and cannot handle it properly

Tags: vba, excel, insert, row

`Sheet1` is called `Action Items` and `Sheet2` is called `Completed Items`.

Column `J` in `Completed Items` contains values ordered in a drop-down list. Whenever a value is set to `O`, `P` or `D`, this row shall be relocated to `Action Items` in the following way:

- Note that column `A` contains ID numbers from row `5` to row `1005` in *both* sheets.
- Let’s say that ID `1` is in row `5`, column `1` of `Completed Items` and ID `2` is in row `5`, column `1` of `Action Items`.
- If I now set `J5` in `Completed Items` to `O`, `P` or `D`, I want the VBA code to insert a new row in `Action Items` and fill that row with the content of the respective row from `Completed Items` in the following way:

  1. Relocate the current `Action Items` row `5` to row `6`, row `6` to row `7`, etc. That is, insert an empty row there where the (unique) ID is *smaller* than the ID in the row below so that in the given example it will be ID `1` in row `5` and ID `2` in row `6` afterwards, etc.
  2. Then, delete the modified row from `Completed Items`.

That is: All the code is doing is relocating a row from one sheet to another. My current code, however, still causes some problems (with `Zeile2` = `Row2` and `Zeile1` = `Row1`):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Zeile2, Zeile1 As Long
    Set Target = Intersect(Target, Range("J5:J1005"))
    If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target = "O" Or Target = "P" Or Target = "D" Then
        Zeile2 = Target.Row
        Zeile1 = 5
        Do While Cells(Zeile2, 1) >= Sheets("Action Items").Cells(Zeile1, 1)
            Zeile1 = Zeile1 + 1
        Loop
        Sheets("Action Items").Cells(Zeile1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        Range(Cells(Zeile2, 1), Cells(Zeile2, 14)).Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Action Items").Cells(Zeile1, 1).End(xlUp)
        Target.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

This code cannot

1. insert an empty row *where* I want to and
2. cannot relocate that row to its meant to be location.

I have tried to change some numbers and have even tried to handle that code that goes as `.End(xlUp)` with an `Offset` option (then being something like `.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`), but nothing has worked out so far.

What am I doing wrong?

*(Unfortunately, I cannot share the Excel file with you, because it’s a business secret.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out what the error was!

Removing `.End(xlUp)` did the thing for me, resulting in the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Zeile2, Zeile1 As Long
    Set Target = Intersect(Target, Range("J5:J1005"))
    If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target = "O" Or Target = "P" Or Target = "D" Then
        Zeile2 = Target.Row
        Zeile1 = 5
        Do While Cells(Zeile2, 1) >= Sheets("Action Items").Cells(Zeile1, 1)
            Zeile1 = Zeile1 + 1
        Loop
        Sheets("Action Items").Cells(Zeile1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        Range(Cells(Zeile2, 1), Cells(Zeile2, 14)).Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Action Items").Cells(Zeile1, 1)
        Target.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace:**

```
If Target = "O" Or Target = "P" Or Target = "D" Then
        Zeile2 = Target.Row
        Zeile1 = 5
        Do While Cells(Zeile2, 1) >= Sheets("Action Items").Cells(Zeile1, 1)
            Zeile1 = Zeile1 + 1
        Loop
        Sheets("Action Items").Cells(Zeile1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        Range(Cells(Zeile2, 1), Cells(Zeile2, 14)).Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Action Items").Cells(Zeile1, 1).End(xlUp)
        Target.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
```

**with:**

```
If Target = "O" Or Target = "P" Or Target = "D" Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
        Zeile2 = Target.Row
        Zeile1 = 5
        Do While Cells(Zeile2, 1) >= Sheets("Action Items").Cells(Zeile1, 1)
            Zeile1 = Zeile1 + 1
        Loop
        Sheets("Action Items").Cells(Zeile1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        Range(Cells(Zeile2, 1), Cells(Zeile2, 14)).Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Action Items").Cells(Zeile1, 1).End(xlUp)
        Target.EntireRow.Delete
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
```

*There may be other problems.*

Comment: why not use `Select Case Taget` , and `Case "O" , "P", " D"` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado  **You may be correct!** ...............my answer only addressed the obvious flaw that I was able to detect by inspection rather than testing.